# Angular setValue is not a function in particular index

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Angular I am facing this issue

```
ERROR TypeError: this.form.value.practiceSet[i].skillone.setValue is not a function
```

In this I need to change the value of the skillone inside the array but I am facing this issue how to fix the value
my ts is

```
skillset(i){
this.form.value.practiceSet[i].skilltwo.setValue(idval)
}
```

My json format is

```
    {
    "game":"football",
     practiceSet:[
        {
           "skillone":"running",
           "skilltwo":"chasing"
         },{
            "skillone":"jump",
             "skilltwo":"gym"
         },
      ]
    }
```

I need to change the value in particular value of "skillone":"running" located in
this.form.value.practiceSet[i].skilltwo.setValue(idval).. I got the value in "idval" but I got error

My HTML is

```
    <ng-container formArrayName="practiceSet" *ngFor="let group of practiceSetArray.controls; let i = index;">
        <tr [formGroupName]="i">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>
               <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput readonly formControlName="Skill set"></mat-form-field>
             </td>
```

My onit (initializing)

```
    this.form = this.fb.group({
    
    practiceSet: this.fb.array([
            this.practiceSetArray()
          ])
        })
    
    
    
    practiceSetArray(){
        let group = new FormGroup({
          skillone: new FormControl(''),
          skilltwo: new FormControl('')
    
    })
    }
```

Comment: Please provide HTML and ts file to check. I will be easy for me to check where it gone wrong. Best Wishes :-)

Comment: ok thanks now I edited my problem above  @ Linker

Comment: You want to the set value for initiation of component.If you want to set the value when component initiation you need to create the formGroup dynamically and insert to formArray

Comment: yes I initialize the form group and form array  @ Msk Satheesh

Comment: get controls and then set. use like following  this.form.value.practiceSet[i].controls.skilltwo.setValue(idval)

Comment: core.js:6260 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined... I got this error  @Msk Satheesh

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular-2wmurr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `setValue()` on an Object.

I believe you are using a reactive forms approach. Consider the line `this.form.value`, after calling `.value` you have a an Object. To get a `FormGroup` instead do below

```typescript
  this.form.get('practiceSet').controls[i].get('skilltwo').setValue(idval)
```

Answer (score 1):

try using:

get your **`formarray`** and assign:

```
(<FormArray>this.form.get("practiceSet")).controls[i]
        .get("skilltwo")
        .setValue(idval);
```

Here the **`stackblitz`** example:

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular-2wmurr?file=src/app/app.component.ts**